# Best practice for saving temporary files in macOS?

Tags: macos, temp

Is there a common practice where to save temporary files on macOS?
Currently I'm using /tmp but I often see the folder /var/folders in use for saving temporary files.

Is there a suggested way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any official guide, but I would say:

- use `/tmp` for temporary things that do not need to survive a reboot
- use `/var/tmp` for temporary things that do need to survive reboot

On my system at least, `/var/folders` is quite restricted in who can access it:

```
drwxr-xr-x  4 root  wheel  136 28 Oct  2015 /var/folders
```